# c# webapi httpget attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing

and looking at the "Get Book Details" section.

I see this code:

```
[HttpGet("api/books/{id}/details")]
public BookDetailDto GetBookDetail(int id)
{
}
```

however I am getting errors that

> HttpGet has 0 parameters but is invoked with 1 argument

(i'm on ASP .net 4.0 WebAPI)

What is the new way of specifying the /details part of the route?

---

my nuget :

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="1.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20715.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

trying to upgrade to the beta version of WEBAPI

```
update-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0-beta2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Update-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0-beta2' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0-beta2'.
Update-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.0.30506.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0-beta2' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.0.0-beta2'.
```

fixed these by retargeting to 4.5 and removing the FixedDisplayModes package

Comment: Are you sure you are using ASP.NET Web API 2, it is unreleated to .Net version, check your NuGet package or assembly version.

Comment: Can you add the URL that you are attempting to use?

Comment: @tpeczek added nuget list.

Comment: @GreyCloud Please change the combobox at the top of Packaga Manager window from "Stable only" to "Include prelease" and upgrade ASP.NET Web API to "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 5.0.0-beta2" (you are currently using version 1 in your project which doesn't support attribute routing).

Comment: @tpeczek wow that's not obvious... the top of the article stated "Web API 2 supports a new type of routing, called attribute routing."

Comment: @GreyCloud Yes, but Web API 2 hasn't been officialy released yet (still beta) --> http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes

Comment: @tpeczek upgrading with nuget is causing problems, any ideas?

Comment: @GreyCloud Usually the problem is "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Fixed DisplayModes" packages (you can try to remove it). You can also switch to ASP.NET Web API nightly builds (http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds) or get the entire Visual Studio 2013 Preview (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=299059)

Comment: @tpeczek Great, that fixed it :) how do I close this question

Comment: @GreyCloud I have provided the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your packages list shows that you are using ASP.NET Web API 1. The support for *Attribute Routing* is available in ASP.NET Web API 2 which is part of [Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/latest/release-notes) and curently in beta version. If you want play with it you have three ways to do this:

- Change the dropdown at the top of Package Manager window value from "Stable only" to "Include prelease" and upgrade your package to `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 5.0.0-beta2` (sometimes the `Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Fixed DisplayModes` package is preventing the update so you might try to remove it first)
- Switch your project to [ASP.NET Web API Nightly Builds](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds)
- [Download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=299059) and install Visual Studio 2013 Preview which comes with proper referencs and new templates.