# I can't access methods in net core MVC controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

EDIT: If I create an empty ASP.NET CORE WEB APP MVC, I can make it working. I am having problem when I am using MVC with Angular. There might be a problem with SPA proxy as well.

EDIT 2: I found a report https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38354
I am still trying but no chance.

I can not access my public methods in controller classes. This is my controller:

```
[Route("authentication")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("example")]
    public IActionResult Example()
    {
        return Ok("This is the Welcome action method...");
    }
}
```

And also I tried this attribute as well:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
```

when I try to navigate to localhost:PORT/authentication/example I am getting 404. I am not using API. I am trying to build a web application with .net core MVC and angular. So I will be just sending GET or POST requests to controllers.

This is my program.cs file

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.Run();
```

I strongly believe that something is wrong in my program.cs. But I couldn't figure it out.

FIX:
After trying out a few days, I finally found the answer. I had to add my new route into 'proxy' variable in proxy.conf.js file.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/weatherforecast",
            "/authentication"
        ],
        target: target,
        secure: false,
        headers: {
            Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
        }}
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show the conventional routing from Program.cs/Startup.cs? `app.UseEndpoints(...)`;

Comment: I dont see [HttpGet] [HttpPost] attributes on your method. Read about them here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673346/c-sharp-webapi-httpget-attribute . Your pipeline has no way to map your call to specific method without these attributes (or relevant routing) thats why you get that error.

Comment: I added my program.cs file. I just created the template project and working on it.

Comment: I also added HttpGet attribute to the method but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this for example, it will work for  localhost:PORT/authentication/example

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
   
    public IActionResult Example()
    {
        return Ok("This is the Welcome action method...");
    }
}

//or 

public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("~/Authentication/Example")]
   public IActionResult Example()
   {
      return Ok("This is the Welcome action method...");
   }
}
```

but since you are using a Controller as a base class, not an ApiController for example, everything should be working even if you remove all attribute routing at all.

Comment: not working. If I create an empty project, yes it is working. But something is wrong with my SPA proxy or Angular. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is that if Your memers start with an action verb, it can find out automatically, like

```
public string GetExample()
```

However you do not want to return raw string, you always want to return an action result, because you want wrapping with explicit HttpStatus response codes, so

```
public IActionResult<string> GetExample()
```

Now many of us a bias towards the works by magic because of prefix and like to be more explicit, not only because the attribute notation allows more control, but also for consistency. Because nearly almost always, at least one action method of the controller actually requires that fine grain.

```
[HttpGet("example")]
public IActionResult<string> Example()
```

Then often for instance there is an id and you can go

```
[HttpGet("example/id?")]
public IActionResult<string> Example([FromRoute] string id)
```

if you want to not have it go through all the places it might be getting your variables from for instance, there are many choices available

Comment: still not working. I tried all attributes, still getting 404.

Answer (score -1):

You need to decorate your controller with method / routing attributes

Try:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("example")]
   public IActionResult Example()
   {
      return Ok("This is the Welcome action method...");
   }
}
```

This will create a get endpoint which can be called at `api/authentication/example`

Returning a 200 status with the text in the body.

Comment: still not working. i think the problem is in program.cs

Comment: for me, often when I hit a stumbling block like this - create a new / out of the box project & copy your changes in... worth a shot if it's taking days.