# Can't access controller method in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to call to methods in `UserController` from my React JS client app.

Here is the `UserController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace xx.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<UserController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<UserController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<UserController>
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] User value)
        {
            return (value.Username.ToString());
        }

        // PUT api/<UserController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<UserController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to access any methods in the `UserController`, I always get a http 404 error:

[image: Error image]

Here is the call from ReactJS client app:

```
function login() {
    var data = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'api/user',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my `Program.cs` file

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "api",
    pattern: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Here is my `setupProxy.js` file, as I was following this solution [I can't access methods in net core MVC controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066246/i-cant-access-methods-in-net-core-mvc-controllers)
but it still doesn't work.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:19824';

const context =  [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/user"
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

I struggling with this problems. Anyone have solution? (sorry for my bad English)

Edit: It's return with a template index.html file when I try to use GET method.

The only controller that work is the weatherforecast (the template one)

Comment: You seem to miss `MapControllers` (rather than `MapControllerRoute`) that sets up routing based on `Route` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to change your react code to access endpoint, Try to change code like:

```
const context =  [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/api/user"
];
```

and if you have fecth() method, you also need to change the url:

```
const response = await fetch('/api/user');
```